# Javascript catch server response in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have written a javascript to post data to a server. This seems to be working but I'm having trouble catching the servers response in iframe. I want to catch the servers response in iframe or in a datastream without forwarding to a other page or refreshing but i will settle with just stopping the page from being forwarded or refreshed.

I have tried adding `target="my_frame"` to the button and the form attributes but it doesn't seem to work.

My code, I slightly modified my code for presentation:

```
 <html>
  <head>

    <title>post</title>

  </head>
  <body>

<script language="javascript">

   var myDictionary = [];
    myDictionary["username"] = "stackoverflow";
    myDictionary["password"] = "mypassword";


function post(dictionary, url, method) {
    method = method || "post"; 

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", url);

    for (key in dictionary) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden"); 
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", dictionary[key]);
        form.appendChild(hiddenField); 
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form); 
    form.submit();
}
</script>

<input type="button" target="my_frame" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:post(myDictionary, 'http://www.website.com/register/registernow');" />

    <iframe name="my_frame" src="">

  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for reading and for all replies.

Comment: add target="<id of iframe>" to the form and id="<id of iframe>" to the iframe, after the form was submitted you can catch the »load« event of the iframe

Comment: I added id="my_Frame" to the iframe and form.setAttribute('target', 'my_Frame'). Now the servers response opens in a new tab. I have also tried adding target="my_Frame" to the button but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is an Ajax POST.

You don't need to create a form and submit it, instead you need XMLHttpRequest,  or if you are using jquery you can use $.post or $.ajax.

See for example http://blog.mgechev.com/2011/07/21/ajax-jquery-beginners/

Comment: If I understood your question - then you are doing it wrong... orm submit will not give you the server response and will trigger a page redirect. You want Ajax to get the server response in javascript without redirecting. I really recommend jquery to do it, but it appears you are not using jquery so the article I linked to shows both jquery and non-jquery ways.